# Python connect oracle database

Tags: python, oracle

```
conn = cx_Oracle.connect('xxx',encoding='GBK')
cursor=conn.cursor()
r= cursor.execute("select * from TB_OBJECT_1063 ")
r.fetchone()
```

I run r.fetchone() for several times and it suddenly give the error,I want the cursor to jump this location and continue to next one

UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 r.fetchone().next()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0xaa in position 203: illegal multibyte sequence

Comment: this is not a connection problem

Comment: Your data in at least one row is not in the encoding you are expecting.

Comment: Yes! There is. So can I jump this row ?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you need try-catch.

```
try:
  r.fetchone()
except UnicodeDecodeError:
  pass
```

and then you may replace `pass` by whatever you need.